# DRF error: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name on nested serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting the following error on DRF:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name 
"quotationitemfile-detail". You may have failed to include the related
model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field`
attribute on this field.
```

I did a Google search on this and it seems an error related to the HyperlinkedModelSerializer, but the thing is that I am not using it, I am using regular serializers:

```py
class QuotationItemFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = QuotationItemFile
        fields = ["id", "url"]


class QuotationItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    files = QuotationItemFileSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = QuotationItem


class QuotationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = QuotationItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Quotation
```

And this error happens when a send a request to a ViewSet using the `QuotationSerializer`.

I also noticed that the error disappears if I comment out the `QuotationItemFileSerializer` so I guess this is something related to DRF falling back to hyperlinks automatically. But I can't seem to get this to work properly.

If I add a ViewSet for the QuotationItemFileSerializer the error stops, but the API returns a hyperlink instead of the serializer data

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was this `url` field in my serializer:

```py
    class Meta:
        model = QuotationItemFile
        fields = ["id", "url"]
```

The `url` field caused DRF to try to generate a hyperlink for the model in my response, therefore causing the error. Removing the `url` fixed my problem